# Windows XP no longer boots

Tags: windows, boot-failure

After installing Ubuntu 11.10 I found that Windows XP will no longer boot. When the system goes to the boot menu, I can see an option for Windows XP, but when I select it the screen goes black for a few seconds and then returns to the boot screen instead of booting Windows XP. I have two hard drives, Windows is on one and Ubuntu is on a partition on the other (I think).

Answer (score 1):

Using your Ubuntu Live CD boot into the system. Once running, open a terminal and type
or copy and paste this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update
```

then

```
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

you will download a repair tool

[image]

To use the tool launch Boot-Repair from either :

the dash (Unity)
System->Administration->Boot-Repair menu (Gnome)

by typing 'boot-repair' in a terminal

Then try "Recommended repair" button. When repair is finished, reboot and check if you recovered access to your OSs.

use this for reference https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair